# How do I run this completed JSP-Project

Tags: java, jsp, wildfly

i just downloaded this OAUTH-JSP Java Program and I don't know how to run it. I tried to use my WildFly JBOSS Server, but it didn't work.

[image: 1]

Thank you in advance

Comment: **but it didn't work**, any detailed information?

Comment: I don't know how to run the index.jsp file. I saw some youtube videos in which they could simply right click and "run" the file. But i don't have the option

Comment: Have you ever run other web application with wildfly?